# Average of time on R

Tags: r

I have some data from different dates and want to know what the average (median or mean) hour that events occur. The problem is that normal averages don't work here as time is circular (e.g. 1 comes after 24). For example, the average of 11pm and 1am should be midnight, but the normal average function would give midday. However, I can't find any functions that are built to do this! Is there a way to do this in R?

```
sleeping_hours <- c(22:30, 21:45, 22:45, 23:40 , 01:00, 23:30)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that computes the mean or the median of dates taking into account that times are circular. The algorithm is simple:

> if a time is before 12:00 it is considered a time of the next day and 86400 seconds (24 hours) are added to it.

It uses a function from package `chron`.

```
mean_circ <- function(x, which = c("mean", "median"), na.rm = FALSE){
  STAT <- match.fun(which)
  if(na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  tm <- paste0(x, ":00")
  d <- as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), tm))
  after_midnight <- chron::times(tm) < chron::times("12:00:00")
  if(any(after_midnight)){
    d[after_midnight] <- d[after_midnight] + 86400
  }
  h <- format(STAT(d), "%H:%M:%S")
  chron::times(h)
}

mean_circ(sleeping_hours, which = "mean")
#[1] 23:11:40
mean_circ(sleeping_hours, which = "median")
#[1] 23:07:30
```

The statistic functions mean and median can be passed without being between quotes.

```
mean_circ(sleeping_hours, which = mean)
#[1] 23:11:40
mean_circ(sleeping_hours, which = median)
#[1] 23:07:30
```